# Decomposing matrix $A$ into $A^{\|}$ and $A^{\perp}$ where $A^{\|}$ and $A^{\perp}$ are perpendicular to each other

Tags: linear-algebra

For a given matrix $V$, I am trying to decompose a matrix $A$ into $A^{\|}$ and $A^{\perp}$ such that

$AV = (A^{\|} +A^{\perp})V = A^{\|}V + A^{\perp}V = \mathbf{0} + A^{\perp}V$,
where $A^{\|}$ and $A^{\perp}$ are orthogonal to each other.

So from what I gather, to do this task, $A^{\|}$ is in the left null space of $V$, so I can first find the null space of $V^T$ by doing SVD for instance (SVD would give orthogonal basis of the null space of $V^T$, which is equal to the left null space of $V$). Then I can project $A$ onto the left null space of $V$ to obtain $A^{\|}$, so I will somehow have to construct the matrix $X$ from the orthogonal basis of the left null space of $V$ so that I can do $A^{\|}= \frac{Tr(A^TX)}{Tr(X^TX)}X$.

The problem I am facing here is I don't know how to construct the matrix $X$ from the orthogonal basis of the left null space of $V$ in such a way that $A^{\|}= \frac{Tr(A^TX)}{Tr(X^TX)}X$ would be orthogonal to $A^{\perp}=A-A^{\|}$ .

How can I do this?

Thank you,

Comment: Are you sure that yoy need $A^{\|}V = 0$? Are you sure that you don't want instead that $A^{\perp}V=0$?

Comment: Yes. I need to find $A^{\perp}$ and $A^{\|}$ that satisfies the above properties.

Comment: you did not answer to my question...

Comment: I do need that $A^{\|}V = 0$.

Comment: Even if I switch the definition for $A^{\|}$ and $A^{\perp}$ and say I want $A^{\perp}V=0$, what difference does it make?

Comment: No difference. I read the question more carefully now. That's ok. When I see something orthogonal, then I think about a null scalar product!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take **any** matrix $X$ whose columns form basis of the left null space of $V$ and define
$$A^\parallel = \frac{\operatorname{tr}(A^TX)}{\operatorname{tr}(X^TX)}X,
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
A^\perp = A-A^\parallel.$$
Then $A=A^\parallel + A^\perp$, $A^\parallel V = 0$ and
\begin{align}
  \operatorname{tr}((A^\parallel)^TA^\perp)
    &= \operatorname{tr}((A^\parallel)^TA)
     - \operatorname{tr}((A^\parallel)^TA^\parallel)\\
    &= \frac{\operatorname{tr}(A^TX)}{\operatorname{tr}(X^TX)}
       \operatorname{tr}(X^TA)
     - \frac{\operatorname{tr}(A^TX)^2}{\operatorname{tr}(X^TX)^2}
       \operatorname{tr}(X^TX)
     = 0,
\end{align}
meaning that $A^\parallel$ and $A^\perp$ are orthogonal.

Comment: Hello,  I am sorry for the late comment. so do you mean that if I take **any** matrix $X$ whose columns form basis of the left null space of $V$ and define
$$A^\parallel = \frac{\operatorname{tr}(A^TX)}{\operatorname{tr}(X^TX)}X,
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
A^\perp = A-A^\parallel.$$, then $A^{||}$ would be orthogonal to $A^{\perp}$? Thank you,

Comment: Yes, $A^\parallel$ and $A^\perp$ are then orthogonal. I've updated my answer to state this explicitly.